# Delete a function in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In VC++ 6 I could right click a function in Class View and delete it.  It would comment out the definition and delete the declaration.

In Visual Studio 2013, that option doesn't appear for me in the context menu (right clicking a function in Class View) and I can't find anywhere else where I can do this.

Is there a quick way to remove a function in Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Try go to the definition, right click the function and click that. If it doesn't appears try with the hotkey F12, maybe vs2013 still using that key to go to the definition of the method or variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "click that"?  F12 will hop me between definition and declaration, but there are no delete option in any of the context menus (right clicking definition or declaration)